# Challenge matching and merging data into a master spreadsheet with data from a new spreadsheet (template attached)

Tags: excel-formula

I have a challenge trying to combine data from a spreadsheet that comes with fresh data from a database into a master spreadsheet that needs to be updated with new data rows, data that is being removed, and data that needs to be modified in the master that is different from the new data spreadsheet.

The data in the “Master” spreadsheet report has been manually modified to upload more accurate information into Power BI dashboards that reflect our operations. The “New Data” spreadsheet (report) is the data source that needs to be combined with the master. The new data comes from a CRM database that cannot be modified for now with the changes manually done to the master spreadsheet. The master spreadsheet will be a template that eventually will be used to modify the CRM database.

Hence, the following are the constraints to combining the “Master” spreadsheet with new data from the database (“New Data” spreadsheet report).

Constraints:

1. “Master” spreadsheet: The master spreadsheet has been manually changed by:
   a.  Adding a new column (Country label) and data (vendor’s country) that is non-existing in the database.
   b.  Replacing some of the data from the “New Data” spreadsheet with data entered manually in the Master such as:
   i.  Replacing data in the Master in columns/fields such as “Finished Product”, “Category Management”, and “Subcategory Management.”
2. “New Data” spreadsheet: The data is pulled from a database, and it is the most current data to be combined with the Master spreadsheet.
   a.  Some of the column/field names are not the same in the Master spreadsheet. “Finished Product”, “Category Management”, and “Subcategory Management” are labelled in the New Data spreadsheet as Industry, Type, and Sub Type.
3. Data Changes: some data from the “New Data” spreadsheet does not exist in the “Master” spreadsheet. New data needs to be combined into the Master, so it may be adding new or replacing existing data in the Master.

Both spreadsheets have been color coded for a better understanding of how their structure and data differ between the “Master” report (manually changed) and the “New Data” report (pulled from the database). Color scheme:

1. Part No.: shows how some parts are being delivered by more than one vendor/supplier.
   a.  The Parts No. is the ‘key identifier’; however, it is duplicated as some parts are shared between different vendors.
2. Country: new column on the “Master” spreadsheet, along with its data, does not exist as a field in the database and so the column doesn’t show on the “New Data” spreadsheet. New data needs to be matched by Part No. and assigned the country as per vendor location.
3. Finished Product: label (column name) is different in the New Data spreadsheet. Also, data from the New Data report has been replaced in the Master.
4. Category Management: label (column name) is different in the New Data spreadsheet. Also, data from the New Data report has been replaced in the Master.
5. Subcategory Management: label (column name) is different in the New Data spreadsheet. Also, data from the New Data report has been replaced in the Master.
6. Data highlighted in cells in red background and white font shows data that is new and needs to be added to the Master. Note that some data in the Master needs to be removed as per the New Data report (e.g., Part No. 2003).
7. Data from the Year 2022 remains the same while for the Year 2023 NEW data needs to be added to the Master, matching and merging data from the Master manually assigned to it. New data moved to Master needs to be updated in Master as per the existing 2023 data matching the data recorded manually. For instance, Part No. 20003 was removed from one vendor and given to another, then reclassified under “Finished Product”, “Category Management”, and “Subcategory Management.”

This matching of new data with data in the Master is one of the main challenges while combining the new data with changes done manually into the Master. The challenge is using a key identifier (Part No.) that is duplicated.

I have tried using Power Query in different ways, VLOOKUp, XLOOKUP, and a combination of INDEX MATCH but find that data is being mixed. I feel that combining this type of data requires a different approach but I’m not sure what would be the right approach to preserving it.

I expect to merge the new data into the Master, without truncating data, and matching new data with the modified data from the Master that doesn’t exist in the database.

[Master Data - Correct photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPHFq.png)

[New Data - Correct photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKvNF.png)

Comment: wowwaahh - my goodness that's a thesis and a -half -like rewrite the Question by crossing out all the irrelevant  bits and focusing/opening wit just the most pertinent /burning Q you want to resolve ~(in as 'laymen' terms a possible, ta J